# Set background inner div on hover/click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two divs:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">Example</div>
</div>
```

And I have a jQuery function:

```
$(function(){
    $('.outer').mouseout(function () {
        $('.outer).attr("style", "background-color: white");
    });

    $('.outer').mouseover(function () {
        $('.outer).attr("style", "background-color: red");
    });

    $('.inner').mouseout(function () {
        $('.inner).attr("style", "background-color: white");
    });

    $('.inner').mouseover(function () {
        $('.inner).attr("style", "background-color: red");
    });
});
```

When I hover over the "outer", the background of the outer is colored red (good!). When I hover the inner, the inner AND outer are colored red... Not good.

The idea is also for the click-event. When I add some click-functions to the jQuery functions and I click the inner div, the script clicks inner and outer div.

I only want one div set to red, not both when I hover the inner. Also for the future, i want to use this functionality for the click-event.

I think this is really simple, but I can't figure it out somehow :(

Who can help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you add background color on hover to parent div it will display in child div even if you keep the child div tansparent. Better you give the child div some other color you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) event method, it:

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any
>   parent handlers from being notified of the event.

So the solution can be as follows:

```
$(".inner").hover(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).attr("style", "background-color: red");
}, function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).attr("style", "background-color: white");
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/TZjpT/

Answer (score 0):

@Zoltan Toth:
I typed it by hand, so I might forgotten some quotes :)

For all others:
I closed stackoverflow and there was a webpage with a possible answer for the problem in the background. I did not see it... And it fixed my problem:

(element = a div)

```
 $(element).bind("click", function (event) {
     $(this).attr("style", "background-color: red");
     event.stopPropagation();
 });
```

Sorry for the inconvenience